# Why messages from en.json are not translated in vue 3 + i18n

Tags: vue.js, internationalization

I have created a default vue2 + i18n project. in en.json (in lacales folder) I have

```
{
  "message": "hello i18n !!"
}
```

HelloWorld component code is

```html
<template>
  <p>{{ $t("message") }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  mounted() {
    alert(this.$t("message"));
  },
};
</script>

<i18n>
{
  "en": {
    "hello": "Hello i18n in SFC!"
  }
}
</i18n>
```

At startup, the lines will be translated and I will get an alert "hello i18n !!"
However, I will also receive warnings.

```
Value of key 'message' is not a string or function !

Fall back to translate the keypath 'message' with root locale.
```

But if I create a vue project with + and i18n I also get warnings but the translation will not come. (this only comes with the lines in the locales folder, using vue 2 and vue 3)
However, translations created in the tag do not cause errors, why does this happen?

Comment: but "message" is defined at src/locales/en.json Can I make something so that i18n can see in json file

Comment: Please make the vue version clear. Is it vue 2 or vue 3? In title you are saying it's vue 3 and in the first line you are saying it's vue 2.

Comment: In both I get a warning about not found translation, but in vue 2 the translation comes,  in vue 3 it doesn't

Comment: Can you add your i18n version from `package.json`?